# Why can't I see any Pokemon on the map or my buddy pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

It's never done this before until I updated Pokemon Go. I can't see any pokemon on the map, (I can see the little rings where the Pokemon appears but can't actually see the Pokemon which prevents me from taping on it and catching it) and i can't see my buddy pokemon(Ivysaur), i can see him in the little circle beside my avater when im walking, but when I tap on my avater I can't see ivysaur, when i try taping on the invisible ivysaur It does nothing, so I can't so how far I've walked for him. And I have a problem with gyms, when I try to battle, my pokemon and the pokemon that I'm fighting won't show up on the screen. I've tried force stopping the app and even tried restarting my phone, but the pokemon still don't show up.

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: Do you have any screenshots?

Comment: Yeah some additional screenshots just as other additional information might be useful. I.E. do you have a rooted device? Have your symptoms appeared just shortly after you updated? And by you saying your Ivysaur doesn't appear on your trainer profile, does this mean you are nevertheless able to choose a buddy?

Comment: Data corruption perhaps. Try to remove the app completely and re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried deleting and reinstalling?  that all ways helps for me if I have a problem, are any visible landmarks missing, like buildings, gyms or pokestops? this may be a rare bug about it though, or you might not have their images loaded/have a bad enough connection that it can bearaly run